Firebase app creating API keys automatically at every deployment
I have a GCP project using Firebase, with two applications. One is used only for the Firebase Authentication tool in my main web app (not hosted with Firebase) - call it APP1.
The other one is an internal app, hosted with Firebase Hosting (also using Firebase Auth) - call it APP2.
APP1 has an API key automatically created by Firebase, on which I configured some restrictions (on the APIs it can use) - call it KEY1.
Now every time I deploy APP2, it seems to create a new API key (visible in the GCP console "API and services"/"credentials" page), with a default set of APIs enabled (call it KEY2, though there may be several of them).
I configure the firebase SDK in APP2 to use the API key KEY1: no part of my code is using the key KEY2. However, when I log in to APP2, it still seems to make some API calls to the google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.ProjectConfigService.GetProjectConfig API using KEY2. I absolutely can't wrap my head around why Firebase would do this, and the documentation has been unhelpful. Is anyone around familiar with Firebase and how it handles API keys?
(PS: I'm using something as below to deploy the hosted app
- name: "Deploy to ${{ inputs.environment }} using Firebase"
  uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
  with:
    repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
    firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}"
    projectId: "${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}"
    channelId: live

)
PS2: the browser makes three requests to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig when I login, two of which are made with KEY1 and one of which is made with KEY2
